# How can I add components inside of another component in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm new in Storybook and I'm trying to test a navigation menu that could contain one or more text links with certain props  (molecules in Storybook).

I already added stories (tests) to the text link component and now I'm trying to add several text links to this nav menu.

```
const LinkOptions = [
  { label: 'Link 1', underline: 'hover', href: '/link1' },
  { label: 'Link 2', underline: 'hover', href: '/link2' },
  { label: 'Link 3', underline: 'hover', href: '/link3' },
  { label: 'Link 4', underline: 'hover', href: '/link4' },
  { label: 'Link 5', underline: 'hover', href: '/link5' },
  { label: 'Link 6', underline: 'hover', href: '/link6' },
];

const Template = (args) => <NavMenu {...args} />;
const LinkTemplate = (args) => <TextLink {...args} />;

export const Desktop = Template.bind({});
export const Link = LinkTemplate.bind({});

{/* <NavMenu options=[] {...args} />; */}

Desktop.args = {
  options: [
    LinkOptions.forEach((option) => {
      Link.args = option;
    }),
  ],
  ariaLabel: 'Navigation Menu',
};
```

I'm trying to create this:

```
<nav aria-label='Navigation Menu'>
  <a href="/link1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="/link2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="/link3">Link 3</a>
  ...
</nav>
```

Is this possible? or can you guide me if I should use .map instead of forEach?
My plan is to create one story for Desktop, one for Table, one for mobile, interact with hover, pressing tab key, etc, so I would like to reuse 'LinkOptions' with slice() sending less values.

Thanks for your help.